# Renaming headers of XSSFTable with Apache Poi leads to corrupt XLSX-file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to rename headers of an existing xlsx-file. The idea is to have an excel-file to export data from XML to excel and reimport the XML once some user has made adjustments.

At the moment we have created a "template" xlsx-sheet with Excel which already contains a sortable table (XSSFTable in poi) and a mapping to a XSD-source. Then we import it via POI, map XML data into it and save it. To adjust the sheet to the users we want to translate the headers/column-names of this existing table into different languages. It worked with POI 3.10-FINAL but since an upgrade to 4.0.1 it leads to a corrupt xlsx-file when opening.

I found this question on stackoverflow already 
[Excel file gets corrupted when i change the value of any cell in the header (Columns Title)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490566/excel-file-gets-corrupted-when-i-change-the-value-of-any-cell-in-the-header-col)
but it is not answered and pretty old. But I tried to figure out what the comments may were about and tried to flatten the existing XSSFTable, copy the filled data to a new sheet and put on a new XSSFTable to the data. Sadly this seems to be pretty complicated so I am back to correcting the broken header-cells.
I also tried to create the whole sheet with POI and step away from using that "template"-xslx, but I cannot figure out how to implement our XSD-Mapping (in Excel its Developer-Tools -> Source -> Add and then mapping the nodes to some cells in a dynamic table)

The code that worked until the upgrade of poi is basically this:

```java
//Sheet is the current XSSFSheet
//header is a Map with the original header-name from the template mapped to a the new translated name
//headerrownumber is the row containing the tableheader to be translated

 public static void translateHeaders(Sheet sheet,final Map<String,String> header,int headerrownumber) {
  CellRangeAddress address = new CellRangeAddress(headerrownumber,headerrownumber,0,sheet.getRow(headerrownumber).getLastCellNum());  //Cellrange is the header-row

        MyCellWalk cellWalk = new MyCellWalk (sheet,address);
        cellWalk.traverse(new CellHandler() {
            public void onCell(Cell cell, CellWalkContext ctx) {
                String val = cell.getStringCellValue();
                if (header.containsKey(val)) {
                    cell.setCellValue(header.get(val));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

MyCellWalk is a org.apache.poi.ss.util.cellwalk.CellWalk which traverses the cell range from top left to the bottom right cell.

As far as I could figure out its not enough to simply change the flat value of the cell because xlsx keeps references to the cellname in some of their maps, but I cannot figure out how to grab them all and rename the header. Maybe there is also another approach in translating the headernames?

Comment: As you know already, the problem comes from the fact that headers in a `XSSFTable` are not only simply text content in the sheet but also names of `XSSFTableColumn`s **and** as column specifiers like `[ColumnName]` parts of structured references. So all this needs to be changed when headers of a `XSSFTable`needs to be changed.

Comment: First what I would try is whether calling [XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--)  and [XSSFTable.updateReferences](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateReferences--), after the header cell values was changed in the sheet, solves the problem.

Comment: I already tried the updateHeaders and updateReferences but sadly it did not work. The table was still corruped then opening.
Do have any hint where I can find, which structured references need to be changed?

Comment: "Do have any hint where I can find, which structured references need to be changed?": No, not without having the "template" xlsx file here. There are so much different possibilities.

Comment: I uploaded a dummy xlsx which is essentially what I use for my project: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jEM2AL8LnAvVLETG2DWSjRoehmMLbnj6/view) on google drive. 
There is an XSD mapped into the table and also on top behind "reference". 

I am also open to other workarounds except updating all references but I'm really out of ideas right now. I'm trying to solve this for a while now and I feel really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--) should do the trick if  `apache poi` would not fail doing it.

All the following is done using `apache poi 4.0.1`.

I have downloaded your `dummy_template.xlsx` and then tried changing the table column headers in the sheet. But even after calling `XSSFTable.updateHeaders` the column names in the `XSSFTable` has not changed. So I had a look into [XSSFTable.java -> updateHeaders](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.java?view=markup#l795) to determine why this not happens. There we find:

```
if (row != null && row.getCTRow().validate()) {
 //do changing the column names
}
```

So the column names only will be changed if the corresponding row in the sheet is valid `XML` according to `Office Open XML` name spaces. But in later `Excel` versions (after 2007) additional name spaces were added. In this case the row's `XML` looks like:

```
<row r="4" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
```

Note the additional `x14ac:dyDescent` attribute. That's why `row.getCTRow().validate()` returns `false`.

The following code gets your `dummy_template.xlsx`, renames the column headers in the sheet and then calls a disarmed version  `static void updateHeaders(XSSFTable table)`. After that the `result.xlsx` is valid for opening in `Excel`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.cellwalk.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ExcelRenameTableColumns {

 static void translateHeaders(Sheet sheet, final Map<String,String> header, int headerrownumber) {
  CellRangeAddress address = new CellRangeAddress(
   headerrownumber, headerrownumber, 
   0, sheet.getRow(headerrownumber).getLastCellNum());

  CellWalk cellWalk = new CellWalk (sheet, address);
  cellWalk.traverse(new CellHandler() {
   public void onCell(Cell cell, CellWalkContext ctx) {
    String val = cell.getStringCellValue();
    if (header.containsKey(val)) {
     cell.setCellValue(header.get(val));
    }
   }
  });
 }

 static void updateHeaders(XSSFTable table) {
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)table.getParent();
  CellReference ref = table.getStartCellReference();

  if (ref == null) return;

  int headerRow = ref.getRow();
  int firstHeaderColumn = ref.getCol();
  XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

System.out.println(row.getCTRow().validate()); // false!

  if (row != null /*&& row.getCTRow().validate()*/) {
   int cellnum = firstHeaderColumn;
   CTTableColumns ctTableColumns = table.getCTTable().getTableColumns();
   if(ctTableColumns != null) {
    for (CTTableColumn col : ctTableColumns.getTableColumnList()) {
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
     if (cell != null) {
      col.setName(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
     }
     cellnum++;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String templatePath = "dummy_template.xlsx";
  String outputPath = "result.xlsx";

  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(templatePath);
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
  header.put("textone", "Spalte eins");
  header.put("texttwo", "Spalte zwei");
  header.put("textthree", "Spalte drei");

  translateHeaders(sheet, header, 3);

  XSSFTable table = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).getTables().get(0);

  updateHeaders(table);

  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
  workbook.write(outputStream);
  outputStream.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

If I open the `dummy_template.xlsx` using `Excel 2007` and then save as `dummy_template2007.xlsx`, the row's `XML` changes to

`<row r="4" spans="1:3">`

Now when using this `dummy_template2007.xlsx` no manually calling the `XSSFTable.updateHeaders` is necessary. The [XSSFTable.writeTo](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.java?view=markup#l114) which is called by `XSSFTable.commit` does this automatically.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This solved my problem - I would have never guessed this myself...how tricky!