# Java edit bar chart in ppt by using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, bar-chart, powerpoint

I am a newbie to using POI at work.Now i'm going to use POI in java to read a bar chart in the PPT.I've added several series x to it in advance,which are the column headers of the excel to which the bar graph belongs.
But i can only read the first three columns by default with the POI.In addition,once I modify the column header of the bar chart,or want to add a fourth column(thar is,add a color)to a bar chart with only three columns, the bar chart cannot be edited when I open the PPT,indicating that the node of the bar chart is damaged.
So is there a master who can help talking how to use POI to prroperly add a color to the bar chart(add a series)?

Eg: when I debug to the "
long ptCatCnt = catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtCount().getVal();
It show nullpointerexecption, I don't know how structure in ppt the bar-chart is.So I want know how to update the bar-chart。

The code is :

public class PPTDemo {

```
public void run() {
    try {
        SlideShow slideShow = SlideShowFactory.create(new File("./res/1.pptx"));

        for (Object o : slideShow.getSlides()) {
            XSLFSlide slider = (XSLFSlide) o;

            // 第一页
            if (slider.getSlideNumber() == 1) {
                for (POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart part : slider.getRelationParts()) {
                    POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart = part.getDocumentPart();
                    // 是图表
                    if (documentPart instanceof XSLFChart) {
                        XSLFChart chart = (XSLFChart) documentPart;

                        // 查看里面的图表数据，才能知道是什么图表
                        CTPlotArea plot = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();

                        // 测试数据
                        List<SeriesData> seriesDatas = Arrays.asList(
                                new SeriesData("", Arrays.asList(
                                        new NameDouble("行1", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行2", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行3", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行4", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行5", Math.random() * 100)
                                )),
                                new SeriesData("", Arrays.asList(
                                        new NameDouble("行1", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行2", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行3", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行4", Math.random() * 100),
                                        new NameDouble("行5", Math.random() * 100)
                                ))
                        );
                        XSSFWorkbook workbook = chart.getWorkbook();
                        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


                        // 柱状图
                        if (!plot.getBarChartList().isEmpty()) {
                            CTBarChart barChart = plot.getBarChartArray(0);
                            updateChartExcelV(seriesDatas, workbook, sheet);
                            workbook.write(chart.getPackagePart().getOutputStream());

                            int i = 0;
                            for (CTBarSer ser : barChart.getSerList()) {
                                updateChartCatAndNum(seriesDatas.get(i), ser.getTx(), ser.getCat(), ser.getVal());
                                ++i;
                            }
                        }

                        // 饼图
                        else if (!plot.getPieChartList().isEmpty()) {
                            // 示例饼图只有一列数据
                            updateChartExcelV(Arrays.asList(seriesDatas.get(0)), workbook, sheet);
                            workbook.write(chart.getPackagePart().getOutputStream());

                            CTPieChart pieChart = plot.getPieChartArray(0);
                            int i = 0;
                            for (CTPieSer ser : pieChart.getSerList()) {
                                updateChartCatAndNum(seriesDatas.get(i), ser.getTx(), ser.getCat(), ser.getVal());
                                ++i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        try {
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./res/o1.pptx")) {
                slideShow.write(out);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * 更新图表的关联 excel， 值是纵向的
 *
 * @param param
 * @param workbook
 * @param sheet
 */
protected void updateChartExcelV(List<SeriesData> seriesDatas, XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFRow title = sheet.getRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesDatas.size(); i++) {
        SeriesData data = seriesDatas.get(i);
        if (data.name != null && !data.name.isEmpty()) {
            // 系列名称，不能修改，修改后无法打开 excel
            //                title.getCell(i + 1).setCellValue(data.name);
        }
        int size = data.value.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j + 1);
            if (row == null) {
                row = sheet.createRow(j + 1);
            }
            NameDouble cellValu = data.value.get(j);
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(0);
            }
            cell.setCellValue(cellValu.name);

            cell = row.getCell(i + 1);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(i + 1);
            }
            cell.setCellValue(cellValu.value);
        }
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if (lastRowNum > size) {
            for (int idx = lastRowNum; idx > size; idx--) {
                sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(idx));
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 更新 chart 的缓存数据
 *
 * @param data          数据
 * @param serTitle      系列的标题缓存
 * @param catDataSource 条目的数据缓存
 * @param numDataSource 数据的缓存
 */
protected void updateChartCatAndNum(SeriesData data, CTSerTx serTitle, CTAxDataSource catDataSource,
                                    CTNumDataSource numDataSource) {

    // 更新系列标题
    //        serTitle.getStrRef().setF(serTitle.getStrRef().getF()); //
    //        serTitle.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtArray(0).setV(data.name);

    // TODO cat 也可能是 numRef
    long ptCatCnt = catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtCount().getVal();
    long ptNumCnt = numDataSource.getNumRef().getNumCache().getPtCount().getVal();
    int dataSize = data.value.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        NameDouble cellValu = data.value.get(i);
        CTStrVal cat = ptCatCnt > i ? catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtArray(i)
                : catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().addNewPt();
        cat.setIdx(i);
        cat.setV(cellValu.name);

        CTNumVal val = ptNumCnt > i ? numDataSource.getNumRef().getNumCache().getPtArray(i)
                : numDataSource.getNumRef().getNumCache().addNewPt();
        val.setIdx(i);
        val.setV(String.format("%.2f", cellValu.value));

    }

    // 更新对应 excel 的range
    catDataSource.getStrRef().setF(
            replaceRowEnd(catDataSource.getStrRef().getF(),
                    ptCatCnt,
                    dataSize));
    numDataSource.getNumRef().setF(
            replaceRowEnd(numDataSource.getNumRef().getF(),
                    ptNumCnt,
                    dataSize));

    // 删除多的
    if (ptNumCnt > dataSize) {
        for (int idx = dataSize; idx < ptNumCnt; idx++) {
            catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().removePt(dataSize);
            numDataSource.getNumRef().getNumCache().removePt(dataSize);
        }
    }
    // 更新个数
    catDataSource.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtCount().setVal(dataSize);
    numDataSource.getNumRef().getNumCache().getPtCount().setVal(dataSize);
}

/**
 * 替换 形如： Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4 的字符
 *
 * @param range
 * @return
 */
public static String replaceRowEnd(String range, long oldSize, long newSize) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(:\\$[A-Z]+\\$)(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(range);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        long old = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(2));
        return range.replaceAll("(:\\$[A-Z]+\\$)(\\d+)", "$1" + Long.toString(old - oldSize + newSize));
    }
    return range;
}

/**
 * 一个系列的数据
 */
public static class SeriesData {

    /**
     * value 系列的名字
     */
    public String name;

    public List<NameDouble> value;

    public SeriesData(java.util.List<NameDouble> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public SeriesData(String name, List<NameDouble> value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public SeriesData() {
    }
}


/**
 *
 */
public class NameDouble {

    public String name;

    /**
     */
    public double value;

    public NameDouble(String name, double value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public NameDouble() {
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Well, seems your code does something wrong.But what code? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially after heading **Help others reproduce the problem**.

Comment: sorry, sir, I made a mistake in asking. I have managed to attach the code to the question.please kindly advise.

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? If it is a current one, then usage of the underlying `ooxml-schemas` classes is not necessary. Using those `CT...` classes is error prone if one does not have really good knowledge about the internally `XML` structure.

Answer (score 4):

Using current `apache poi 5.0.0` updating a chart in `PowerPoint` is possible using the new `XDDF` classes. That avoids using the `ooxml-schemas` classes (`CT...` classes) directly. Using `CT` classes directly is error prone and needs very good knowlegde about the internally `XML` structure of `Office Open XML`.

What one needs to know is that chart data is stored in an embedded `Excel` workbook. So while updating the data the need is always updating the data in that workbook and updating the data in the chart.

The following example is a minimal reproducible example for how to do this.

The template `BarChartSample.pptx` contained a bar chart having only one series an one category. It defines the chart format. It looks like so:

[image]

The code is like this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;

public class PowerPointChangeChartData {

 //patched version of XSSFTable.updateHeaders, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532006/renaming-headers-of-xssftable-with-apache-poi-leads-to-corrupt-xlsx-file/55539181#55539181
 static void updateHeaders(XSSFTable table) {
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)table.getParent();
  CellReference ref = table.getStartCellReference();

  if (ref == null) return;

  int headerRow = ref.getRow();
  int firstHeaderColumn = ref.getCol();
  XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  if (row != null /*&& row.getCTRow().validate()*/) {
   int cellnum = firstHeaderColumn;
   CTTableColumns ctTableColumns = table.getCTTable().getTableColumns();
   if(ctTableColumns != null) {
    for (CTTableColumn col : ctTableColumns.getTableColumnList()) {
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
     if (cell != null) {
      col.setName(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
     }
     cellnum++;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 static void updateChart(XSLFChart chart, Object[][] data) throws Exception {
  // get chart's data source which is a Excel sheet
  XSSFWorkbook chartDataWorkbook = chart.getWorkbook();
  String sheetName = chartDataWorkbook.getSheetName(0);
  XSSFSheet chartDataSheet = chartDataWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
  // current Office uses a table as data source
  // so get that table if present
  XSSFTable chartDataTable = null;
  if (chartDataSheet.getTables().size() > 0) {
   chartDataTable = chartDataSheet.getTables().get(0);
  }

  if (chart.getChartSeries().size() == 1) { // we will process only one chart data
   XDDFChartData chartData = chart.getChartSeries().get(0);
   if (chartData.getSeriesCount() == 1) { // we will process only templates having one series

    int rMin = 1; // first row (0) is headers row
    int rMax = data.length - 1;

    // set new category data
    XDDFCategoryDataSource category = null;
    int c = 0;
    for (int r = rMin; r <= rMax; r++) {
     XSSFRow row = chartDataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = chartDataSheet.createRow(r);
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]); // in sheet
    }
    category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); // in chart

    // series 1, is present already 
    c = 1;

    // set new values in sheet and in chart
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = null;
    for (int r = rMin; r < rMax+1; r++) {
     XSSFRow row = chartDataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = chartDataSheet.createRow(r);
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]); // in sheet
    }
    values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); 
    XDDFChartData.Series series1 = chartData.getSeries(0);
    series1.replaceData(category, values); // in chart

    // set new title in sheet and in chart
    String series1Title = (String)data[0][c];
    chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(c).setCellValue(series1Title); // in sheet
    series1.setTitle(series1Title, new CellReference(sheetName, 0, c, true, true)); // in chart

    series1.plot(); 

    //further series, all new created
    int seriesCount = data[0].length - 1;
    for (int s = 2; s <= seriesCount; s++) {
     c++;

     // set new values
     for (int r = rMin; r < rMax+1; r++) {
      XSSFRow row = chartDataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = chartDataSheet.createRow(r);
      XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]); // in sheet
     }
     values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); 
     XDDFChartData.Series series = chartData.addSeries(category, values); // in chart
 
     // set new title
     String seriesTitle = (String)data[0][c];
     XSSFCell cell = chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = chartDataSheet.getRow(0).createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue(seriesTitle); // in sheet
     series.setTitle(seriesTitle, new CellReference(sheetName, 0, c, true, true)); // in chart

     series.plot();
    }

    // update the table if present
    if (chartDataTable != null) {
     CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0));
     CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(chartDataSheet.getRow(rMax).getCell(c));
     AreaReference tableArea = chartDataWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
     chartDataTable.setArea(tableArea);
     updateHeaders(chartDataTable);
    }

   }
  }
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "BarChartSample.pptx"; // has template bar chart
  String filePathNew = "BarChartSample_New.pptx";

  Object[][] data = new Object[][] { // new data 3 series, 5 categories
   {"", "Amount", "Values", "Others"}, // series title
   {"Jan", 321d, 456d, 222d}, // category 1
   {"Feb", 543d, 567d, 111d}, // category 2
   {"Mar", 432d, 123d, 333d}, // category 3
   {"Apr", 210d, 234d, 444d}, // category 4
   {"May", 198d, 345d, 444d} // category 5
  };

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(filePath));

  XSLFChart chart = slideShow.getCharts().get(0);

  updateChart(chart, data);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePathNew); 
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }

}
```

The result looks like so:

[image]

Hint: The code uses a patched version of `XSSFTable.updateHeaders` as the current version fails updating the table headers. See [Renaming headers of XSSFTable with Apache Poi leads to corrupt XLSX-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532006/renaming-headers-of-xssftable-with-apache-poi-leads-to-corrupt-xlsx-file/55539181#55539181).

Comment: If it's scatter chart, it does not have category (<c:cat>), there only are `c:xVal`, `c:yVal`,`c:extLst`. In this case--without category, how to replaceData? `series1.replaceData(category, values)`