# Update existing chart data(.xlsx file) in a Powerpoint slide using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I want to update and refresh existing chart in a Powerpoint slide using apache poi.I am able to read the embedded excel and update it. How do I update the chart with the updated excel data?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774234/java-edit-bar-chart-in-ppt-by-using-poi/66777798#66777798