# Update existing pie chart apache poi ppt

Tags: java, apache-poi, backend

I am trying to update an existing pie chart that has its own colors and style. Then I want to update the pie chart but keeping the format and style of the pie chart. Currently I am able to update the pie chart but losing the format/style and cannot update the first value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wDBl.png)

To populate I am doing this:

```
    static void updatePieChart(XSLFChart chart, List<User> users) throws Exception {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = chart.getWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        users.stream()
                .forEach(value -> addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, user.getName(), user.getSavings()));
    }
    
    static void addDataToChart(XSSFSheet sheet, XSLFChart chart, String month, Double value) {
        Row row;
        Cell cell;

        List<XDDFChartData> chartDataList = chart.getChartSeries();
        XDDFChartData chartData = chartDataList.get(0);

        List<XDDFChartData.Series> seriesList = chartData.getSeries();
        for (XDDFChartData.Series series : seriesList) {
            XDDFDataSource categoryData = series.getCategoryData();
            AreaReference catReference = new AreaReference(categoryData.getDataRangeReference(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
            CellReference firstCatCell = catReference.getFirstCell();
            CellReference lastCatCell = catReference.getLastCell();
            if (firstCatCell.getCol() == lastCatCell.getCol()) {
                int col = firstCatCell.getCol();
                int lastRow = lastCatCell.getRow();

                row = sheet.getRow(lastRow + 1);
                if (row == null)
                    row = sheet.createRow(lastRow + 1);

                cell = row.getCell(col);
                if (cell == null)
                    cell = row.createCell(col);
                cell.setCellValue(month);

                XDDFDataSource<String> category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(
                        sheet,
                        new CellRangeAddress(firstCatCell.getRow(), lastRow+1, col, col));

                XDDFNumericalDataSource valuesData = series.getValuesData();
                AreaReference numReference = new AreaReference(valuesData.getDataRangeReference(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
                CellReference firstNumCell = numReference.getFirstCell();
                CellReference lastNumCell = numReference.getLastCell();
                if (lastNumCell.getRow() == lastRow && firstNumCell.getCol() == lastNumCell.getCol()) {
                    col = firstNumCell.getCol();
                    row = sheet.getRow(lastRow+1);

                    if (row == null)
                        row = sheet.createRow(lastRow + 1);

                    cell = row.getCell(col);
                    if (cell == null)
                        cell = row.createCell(col);

                    cell.setCellValue(value);

                    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(
                            sheet,
                            new CellRangeAddress(firstNumCell.getRow(), lastRow + 1, col, col));

                    series.replaceData(category, values);
                }
            }
        }
        chart.plot(chartData);
    }
```

This is the result I am having
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHOyR.png)
As you can see the legend and the slice of the pie are different (first one vs the other rows added) also the rows in the worksheet lost the format of the first one, even the first row is not being removed/updated in order to show only since "Kate row".

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: @AxelRichter do you know maybe why I am having this result? or should I do it in another way?. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs into following problems:

First, you should update the chart data for `XDDF` (the chart plot) and for `XSSF` (the data table source) in parallel and not separate. As you can see, a separate update may result in a loss of synchronicity.

This I have shown in [Java edit bar chart in ppt by using poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774234/java-edit-bar-chart-in-ppt-by-using-poi/66777798#66777798) for a bar chart already.

Second, if you want to remain possible cell styles, as currency number style for example, then you need to code this too. It will not remain automatically, as you are creating new cells.

Following complete example adopts my example for a bar chart to update a pie chart.

Template `PieChartSample.pptx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;

public class PowerPointChangeChartDataPieChart  {

 static void updateChart(XSLFChart chart, Object[][] data) throws Exception {
  // get chart's data source which is a Excel sheet
  XSSFWorkbook chartDataWorkbook = chart.getWorkbook();
  String sheetName = chartDataWorkbook.getSheetName(0);
  XSSFSheet chartDataSheet = chartDataWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
  // current Office uses a table as data source
  // so get that table if present
  XSSFTable chartDataTable = null;
  if (chartDataSheet.getTables().size() > 0) {
   chartDataTable = chartDataSheet.getTables().get(0);
  }

  if (chart.getChartSeries().size() == 1) { // we will process only one chart data
   XDDFChartData chartData = chart.getChartSeries().get(0);
   if (chartData.getSeriesCount() == 1) { // we will process only templates having one series

    int rMin = 1; // first row (0) is headers row
    int rMax = data.length - 1;

    // set new category data
    XDDFCategoryDataSource category = null;
    int c = 0;
    for (int r = rMin; r <= rMax; r++) {
     XSSFRow row = chartDataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = chartDataSheet.createRow(r);
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]); // in sheet
    }
    category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); // in chart

    // series 1, is present already and a pie chart only has one series
    c = 1;

    // set new values in sheet and in chart
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = null;
    // to remain possible cell styles
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = null;
    for (int r = rMin; r < rMax+1; r++) {
     XSSFRow row = chartDataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = chartDataSheet.createRow(r);
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]); // in sheet
     // remain possible cell styles
     if (cellStyle == null) cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
     cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
    values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); 
    XDDFChartData.Series series1 = chartData.getSeries(0);
    series1.replaceData(category, values); // in chart

    // set new title in sheet and in chart
    String series1Title = (String)data[0][c];
    chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(c).setCellValue(series1Title); // in sheet
    series1.setTitle(series1Title, new CellReference(sheetName, 0, c, true, true)); // in chart

    series1.plot(); 

    //no further series as a pie chart only has one series
    
    // update the table if present
    if (chartDataTable != null) {
     CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0));
     CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(chartDataSheet.getRow(rMax).getCell(c));
     AreaReference tableArea = chartDataWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
     chartDataTable.setArea(tableArea);
     chartDataTable.updateHeaders();
    }

   }
  }
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "./PieChartSample.pptx"; // has template pie chart
  String filePathNew = "./PieChartSample_New.pptx";

  Object[][] data = new Object[][] { // new data 1 series, 6 categories
   {"User", "Savings"}, // series title
   {"Kate", 200d}, // category 1
   {"Michael", 500d}, // category 2
   {"Charles", 452.54d}, // category 3
   {"Franklin", 864.1d}, // category 4
   {"Dina", 422.9d}, // category 5
   {"Peter", 7458.4} // category 6
  };

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(filePath));

  XSLFChart chart = slideShow.getCharts().get(0);

  updateChart(chart, data);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePathNew); 
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }

}
```

Result `PieChartSample_New.pptx`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Axel. Just a doubt, if would like to show only data labels when are greater than a certain percentage, then I should generate the logic based on this methods: getDLbls().getDLblArray(pointCount) ? –

Comment: @Adrian Duran: Applying data label settings for each single data point is laborious. I would do that by setting a special number format to all data labels. `[>0.05]0.0%;` for example will show percent only if greater than 0.05 (5%). But asking follow up questions in comments of an answr is not how StackOverflow works. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.