# XSSFWorkbook cloneSheet corrupts workbook if sheet contains a table

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to clone an Excel sheet and all of its contents. I tried the [XSSFWorkbook cloneSheet method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#cloneSheet-int-java.lang.String-), but it seems the workbook is corrupted if my sheet contains an Excel table. See the examle workbook below with a simple table:

[image]

When I try to open the output workbook, I get a prompt telling me that the file is broken and needs to be repaired. If I recover the workbook, it is clear the table has not been copied correctly; the original totals row is now a data row.

[image]

```java
try (InputStream is = Table.class.getResourceAsStream("table.xlsx")) {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);

    workbook.cloneSheet(0, "Test");

    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("table-2.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How I would go about copying this sheet? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XSSFWorkbook.cloneSheet` clones a sheet. But it does not considering the possible defined tables in it. It simply clones the table references. But two table-ranges in sheets cannot refer to the same table reference. The tables itself needs to be cloned. That's why the corrupted workbook as result.

I've tried to solve this by programming a method `cloneTables(XSSFSheet sheet)` which simply creates clones of each table in a sheet which then refer to their own table reference each. I consider table styles, auto-filter, a totals-row and calculated column formulas. I hope I have not overlooked something, but I doubt that.

The code its tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2`.

It contains fixes for following bugs too:

[XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--) fails in Excel workbooks created using current Excel versions. This is  because of the test `row.getCTRow().validate()` which always will be false because of the usage of new name spaces. See [Renaming headers of XSSFTable with Apache Poi leads to corrupt XLSX-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532006/renaming-headers-of-xssftable-with-apache-poi-leads-to-corrupt-xlsx-file/55539181#55539181).

[XSSFSheet.removeTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#removeTable-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable-) does not remove the links to the table part reference from the sheet.

Complete example to test:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;

class ExcelCloneSheetHavingTable {
        
 static void updateHeaders(XSSFTable table) {
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)table.getParent();
  CellReference ref = table.getStartCellReference();

  if (ref == null) return;

  int headerRow = ref.getRow();
  int firstHeaderColumn = ref.getCol();
  XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  
  if (row != null /*&& row.getCTRow().validate()*/) { // see bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532006/renaming-headers-of-xssftable-with-apache-poi-leads-to-corrupt-xlsx-file/55539181#55539181
   int cellnum = firstHeaderColumn;
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns ctTableColumns = table.getCTTable().getTableColumns();
   if(ctTableColumns != null) {
    for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn col : ctTableColumns.getTableColumnList()) {
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
     if (cell != null) {
      String colName = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
      colName = colName.replace("\n", "_x000a_");
      colName = colName.replace("\r", "_x000d_");
      col.setName(colName);
     }
     cellnum++;
    }
   }
  }
  //tableColumns = null;
  //columnMap = null;
  //xmlColumnPrs = null;
  //commonXPath = null;
  try {
   java.lang.reflect.Field tableColumns = XSSFTable.class.getDeclaredField("tableColumns");
   tableColumns.setAccessible(true);
   tableColumns.set(table, null);
   java.lang.reflect.Field columnMap = XSSFTable.class.getDeclaredField("columnMap");
   columnMap.setAccessible(true);
   columnMap.set(table, null);
   java.lang.reflect.Field xmlColumnPrs = XSSFTable.class.getDeclaredField("xmlColumnPrs");
   xmlColumnPrs.setAccessible(true);
   xmlColumnPrs.set(table, null);
   java.lang.reflect.Field commonXPath = XSSFTable.class.getDeclaredField("commonXPath");
   commonXPath.setAccessible(true);
   commonXPath.set(table, null);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();   
  }
 }
 
 static String getSubtotalFormulaStartFromTotalsRowFunction(int intTotalsRowFunction) {
  final int INT_NONE = 1;
  final int INT_SUM = 2;
  final int INT_MIN = 3;
  final int INT_MAX = 4;
  final int INT_AVERAGE = 5;
  final int INT_COUNT = 6;
  final int INT_COUNT_NUMS = 7;
  final int INT_STD_DEV = 8;
  final int INT_VAR = 9;
  final int INT_CUSTOM = 10;
  String subtotalFormulaStart = null;
  switch (intTotalsRowFunction) {
   case INT_NONE:
    subtotalFormulaStart = null;
    break;
   case INT_SUM:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(109";
    break;
   case INT_MIN:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(105";
    break;
   case INT_MAX:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(104";
    break;
   case INT_AVERAGE:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(101";
    break;
   case INT_COUNT:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(103";
    break;
   case INT_COUNT_NUMS:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(102";
    break;
   case INT_STD_DEV:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(107";
    break;
   case INT_VAR:
    subtotalFormulaStart = "SUBTOTAL(110";
    break;
   case INT_CUSTOM:
    subtotalFormulaStart = null;
    break;
   default:
    subtotalFormulaStart = null;   
  }
  return subtotalFormulaStart;  
 }
    
 static void cloneTables(XSSFSheet sheet) {
  for (XSSFTable table : sheet.getTables()) {
      
   // clone table; XSSFTable.setArea fails and throws exception for too small tables
   XSSFTable clonedTable = null;
   int rowCount = (table.getArea().getLastCell().getRow() - table.getArea().getFirstCell().getRow()) + 1;
   int headerRowCount = table.getHeaderRowCount(); if (headerRowCount == 0) headerRowCount = 1;
   int minimumRowCount = 1 + headerRowCount + table.getTotalsRowCount();
   if (rowCount >= minimumRowCount) {
    clonedTable = sheet.createTable(table.getArea());
   } 
   
   if (clonedTable != null) {
    //clonedTable.updateHeaders(); // don't work, see bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532006/renaming-headers-of-xssftable-with-apache-poi-leads-to-corrupt-xlsx-file/55539181#55539181
    updateHeaders(clonedTable);
   
    // clone style
    clonedTable.setStyleName(table.getStyleName());
    XSSFTableStyleInfo style = (XSSFTableStyleInfo)table.getStyle();
    XSSFTableStyleInfo clonedStyle = (XSSFTableStyleInfo)clonedTable.getStyle();
    if (style != null && clonedStyle != null) {
     clonedStyle.setShowColumnStripes(style.isShowColumnStripes());
     clonedStyle.setShowRowStripes(style.isShowRowStripes());
     clonedStyle.setFirstColumn(style.isShowFirstColumn());
     clonedStyle.setLastColumn(style.isShowLastColumn());
    }
   
    //clone autofilter
    clonedTable.getCTTable().setAutoFilter(table.getCTTable().getAutoFilter());
   
    //clone totalsrow
    int totalsRowCount = table.getTotalsRowCount();
    if (totalsRowCount == 1) { // never seen more than one totals row
     XSSFRow totalsRow = sheet.getRow(clonedTable.getEndCellReference().getRow());
     if (clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size() > 0) {
      clonedTable.getCTTable().setTotalsRowCount(totalsRowCount);
      for (int i = 0; i < clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size(); i++) {
       org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn tableCol = table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(i);
       org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn clonedTableCol = clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(i);
       clonedTableCol.setTotalsRowFunction(tableCol.getTotalsRowFunction());
       int intTotalsRowFunction = clonedTableCol.getTotalsRowFunction().intValue();
       sheet.getWorkbook().setCellFormulaValidation(false);
       if (intTotalsRowFunction == 10) { //custom
        org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableFormula totalsRowFormula = tableCol.getTotalsRowFormula();
        clonedTableCol.setTotalsRowFormula(totalsRowFormula);
        totalsRow.getCell(clonedTable.getStartCellReference().getCol()+i).setCellFormula(totalsRowFormula.getStringValue());
       } else if (intTotalsRowFunction == 1) { //none
        //totalsRow.getCell(clonedTable.getStartCellReference().getCol()+i).setBlank();
       } else {
        String subtotalFormulaStart = getSubtotalFormulaStartFromTotalsRowFunction(intTotalsRowFunction);
        if (subtotalFormulaStart != null) 
         totalsRow.getCell(clonedTable.getStartCellReference().getCol()+i).setCellFormula(subtotalFormulaStart + "," + clonedTable.getName() +"[" + clonedTableCol.getName()+ "])");
       }
      }
     }
    }
   
    // clone calculated column formulas
    if (clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size() > 0) {
     clonedTable.getCTTable().setTotalsRowCount(totalsRowCount);
     for (int i = 0; i < clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size(); i++) {
      org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn tableCol = table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(i);
      org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn clonedTableCol = clonedTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(i);
      if (tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula() != null) {
       clonedTableCol.setCalculatedColumnFormula(tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula());
       org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableFormula calculatedColumnFormula = clonedTableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula();
       String formula = tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula().getStringValue();
       String clonedFormula = formula.replace(table.getName(), clonedTable.getName());
       calculatedColumnFormula.setStringValue(clonedFormula);
       int rFirst = clonedTable.getStartCellReference().getRow() + clonedTable.getHeaderRowCount();
       int rLast = clonedTable.getEndCellReference().getRow() - clonedTable.getTotalsRowCount();
       int c = clonedTable.getStartCellReference().getCol() + i;
       sheet.getWorkbook().setCellFormulaValidation(false);
       for (int r = rFirst; r <= rLast; r++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
        cell.setCellFormula(clonedFormula);
       }       
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
   // remove old table; do that even if XSSFsheet.createTable failed, because a one-cell-table doesn't make any sense
   String rId = sheet.getRelationId(table);
   sheet.removeTable(table);
   // remove links to the table part reference
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableParts tblParts = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getTableParts();
   if (tblParts != null &&  tblParts.getTablePartList().size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tblParts.getTablePartList().size(); i++) {
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTablePart tblPart = tblParts.getTablePartArray​(i);    
     if(tblPart.getId().equals(rId)) {
      tblParts.removeTablePart​(i);
     }   
    }     
   }
   
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("SAMPLE_NEW.xlsx")) {
           
   XSSFSheet sheet = ((XSSFWorkbook)workbook).cloneSheet(0, "Test");
   cloneTables(sheet);
   
   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas, which is `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar` for `apache poi 5.2.2`, as mentioned in [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025). Note, since `apache poi 5.*` the formerly used `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` cannot be used anymore. There must **not** be any `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` in class path when using `apache poi 5.*`.

Note, you need this additional. The file names `poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar` and `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar` respective `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar` are misleading. The `*-lite*.jar` respective `*-full*.jar` do not replace, but complement the `poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar`.

Comment: What dependencies did you use? Do I need anything else than poi 5.2.2 and poi-ooxml 5.2.2? I don't seem to have CTTableFormula in my classpath.

Comment: You need `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar`. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025.

Comment: Thanks! I also want to clone the names from the source sheet into the new sheet, that is if there are any names with scope set to "sheet" and not "workbook".

I think I have figured it out, the problem is table formulas, e.g. if a name refers to =table[[#Headers];[C]] I would need to replace the table name (in this example "table") with the new sheet name. Do you know if there is any good and reliable way of doing this?

Comment: @emile: "I also want to clone the names from the source sheet ": Not possible for table names. Table names always are on scope workbook. What happens if you try this using Excel's GUI? You will get a message and it wil not work, will it?

Comment: I mean like this: https://imgur.com/a/sIvt3Fu. Test being the new sheet.

Comment: @emile: Always not clear to me. As said, table names always are on scope workbook. Other names may be in different scopes. But this does not belongs to this SO question, which is about tables only. SO is not made to answer all possible questions in one question. So please ask a new question if you have a question about using [XSSFName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFName.html).